# History browser doubles

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, browser, popstate

I've got a problem.
Here is a situation: I have an iframe with a site inside.
Also I have a wrapper with player. 
I need this for singleton player which doesn't stop or refresh when user goes by links on a site.
Using postMessage for cute conversation between wrapper and iframe, I try to trigget history changes (onpopstate) so if user clickes "back" of "forward" my iframe reloads.
I don't undersand why my event works only on the first page in a story (may be not. I still don't get it). And WHYYY OMG **WHY every state of a history doubles there?**
Like this:

1. Musicsets
2. Artists
3. Artist number 34786
4. Search page
5. Go back (now I should have an artist page. My iframe refreshes correctly, but wrapper has the same url and title)
6. Go back again (now changes url of wrapper)

Here is my code of a trigger. And ***please tell me what can be a reason of such a bad behaviour?*** 
**wrapper side**

```
var zaya = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;

window.onpopstate = function(data) {
    zaya.postMessage({
        name: "popstate",
        url: window.location.host + window.location.pathname
    },
        "http://urlofwebsite.com"
    );

    alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

**iframe side**

```
function listenerIF(data) {
    var info = data.data;

    if (data.origin !== "http://urlofwebsite.com") return;

    if (info.name === "popstate") {
        document.location = info.url;
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("message", listenerIF, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenerIF);
}
```

But this trigger doesn't work anyway...

Comment: may be it is because of iframe and it pushes states in a history too? May be there is a way to reject such pushes?

Answer (score 0):

I did never know that iframe adds its history state to the main history. So I fixed it like this:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var neededUrl = this.getAttribute('href');
        /*here is a code with postMessage to wrapper So there will be pushState()*/
        window.location.replace(neededUrl);
    });
```